# list of partial matches in very large lists of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am new to python and I must thank you all for the wonderful discussions out here, but I have a problem I haven't seen any advice on. (Or it was too complicated for me to understand.)

I have two lists (tuples?) each with about one million entries. They are both sorted on the first entry (word) and have the same format. In each list, the word/page combination is unique.

```
List1=  [('word1', 'page1'), ('word1', 'page2'), ('word3', 'page1'),...]
List2 = [('word1', 'page4'), ('word2', 'page2'), ('word3', 'page1'),...]
```

I need to find each 'word' in list1 that also occurs in list2. The output for this example should be

```
[('word1', 'page1'), ('word1', 'page2'), ('word1', 'page4'),('word3','page1')]
```

I've been looking so much that I am now thoroughly confused with sets, lists, tuples, dicts,...I can probably do a for loop but it seems there are better choices out here somewhere.

Comment: My first thought is to perform a set intersection. But I'm worried that the large lists and resulting sets would consume a lot of memory.

Comment: a different data structure could simplify things, would a dict keyed by word with value as a list of pages be more helpful?

Comment: @JamesMills How can I make these lists into sets? I get TypeError "unhashable type" error when I try to make a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there plenty of ways to achieve your scope. Since your data is really large, you have to take performance into account, time or space or performance? Here are examples.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

L1 = [('word1', 'page1'), ('word1', 'page2'), ('word3', 'page1'), ]
L2 = [('word1', 'page4'), ('word2', 'page2'), ('word3', 'page2'), ]

def func1():
    '''
    Time Complexity is O(n^2) 
    '''
    res = []
    for i in L1:
        for k in L2:
            if i[0] == k[0]:
                res.append(i)
                res.append(k)
    return list(set(res))

def func2():
    '''
    Time Complexity is O(n)
    '''
    d1 = {}
    for i in L1:
        if d1.has_key(i[0]):
            d1[i[0]].append(i[1])
        else:
            d1[i[0]] = [i[1]]
    d2 = {}
    for i in L2:
        if d2.has_key(i[0]):
            d2[i[0]].append(i[1])
        else:
            d2[i[0]] = [i[1]]
    d3 = {}
    for key in d1.keys():
        if d2.has_key(key):
            d3[key] = d2[key] + d1[key]

    return [(m,n) for m in d3.keys() for n in d3[m]]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print func1()
    print func2()

    import timeit
    t = timeit.Timer(func1)
    print t.timeit(10000)
    t = timeit.Timer(func2)
    print t.timeit(10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to map words to pages you could use a dict to map words to pages.

```
from collections import defaultdict
word_pages_1 = defauldict(list)
for w, p in List1:
   word_pages_1[w].append(p)
```

you could then perform set operations on your dict keys for comparisons between them

Answer (score 0):

Looks like to be a big data problem. You may want to use specific tools such as `numpy` and `pandas`. If you have enough RAM to fit both data in memory, it can be done in `numpy`:

```
In [103]:
import numpy as np
List1=  [('word1', 'page1'), ('word1', 'page2'), ('word3', 'page1')]
List2 = [('word1', 'page4'), ('word2', 'page2'), ('word3', 'page1')]

In [104]:
arr1 = np.array(List1)
arr2 = np.array(List2)

In [105]:
arr3=np.vstack((arr1, arr2)) #stack two dataset together
arr3

Out[105]:
array([['word1', 'page1'],
       ['word1', 'page2'],
       ['word3', 'page1'],
       ['word1', 'page4'],
       ['word2', 'page2'],
       ['word3', 'page1']], 
      dtype='|S5')

In [106]:
np.in1d(arr3[:,0], arr1[:,0]) 
#for each item in arr3, is the first value appears in the 1st position of arr1?

Out[106]:
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [107]:
arr3[np.in1d(arr3[:,0], arr1[:,0])] #Boolean indexing

Out[107]:
array([['word1', 'page1'],
       ['word1', 'page2'],
       ['word3', 'page1'],
       ['word1', 'page4'],
       ['word3', 'page1']], 
      dtype='|S5')

In [108]:
set(map(tuple, arr3[np.in1d(arr3[:,0], arr1[:,0])]))

Out[108]:
{('word1', 'page1'),
 ('word1', 'page2'),
 ('word1', 'page4'),
 ('word3', 'page1')}
```